# Change Overriden Django Views Return URL

Tags: django

I want to change the return url of a [django-allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth) page.

I know I could override the entire function in views.py and just change the `return` url at the bottom, but doesn't seem ideal as it could cause issues if associated code in the django-allauth package gets changed by the packages authors.

Is there a better way to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I ended up doing this:

```
from allauth.account.views import PasswordChangeView
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.urls import reverse

class CustomPasswordChangeView(LoginRequiredMixin, PasswordChangeView):

    def get_success_url(self):

        if [...]:
            success_url = reverse([...], kwargs={'username': self.request.user.username})
        else:
            success_url = reverse([...], kwargs={'username': self.request.user.username})

        return success_url

custom_password_change = login_required(CustomPasswordChangeView.as_view())
```